# Cycle Detection in a Graph using NetworkX Python

Tags: python, graph, networkx, cycle-detection

My CSV file has ~2.6 million records of transaction among different people. I am trying to make a graph from this file as: person having unique IDs as nodes and edges representing transaction between two people and want to fetch all possible cycles from the graph. I am trying to use `networkx.simple_cycles(graph_name)` to fetch all the cycles from this graph but getting this error:

```
    NetworkXNotImplemented                    Traceback (most recent call 
    last)
    <ipython-input-21-c36e4cd0e220> in <module>()
    ----> 1 nx.simple_cycles(Directed_G)

    <decorator-gen-215> in simple_cycles(G)

    ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
     packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py in _not_implemented_for(f, *args, 
     **kwargs)
     64         if match:
     65             raise nx.NetworkXNotImplemented('not implemented for %s 
     type'%
     ---> 66                                             ' 
     '.join(graph_types))
     67         else:
     68             return f(*args,**kwargs)

     NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for undirected type
```

My Python code looks like this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    import networkx as nx
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    %matplotlib inline

    data=pd.read_csv(path/to/csv/file)
    Directed_G=nx.DiGraph()
    Directed_G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(data, 'from', 'to')
    nx.simple_cycles(Directed_G)
```

My data looks something like this:

```
            from                to  
    0       000028c1f8598db 1a55bc3aab8562f     
    1       00003147f02a255 9c1f54d9859ce12     
    2       00003cdc5ed35a0 472f48d28903b43     
    3       00003cdc5ed35a0 5ab9e7e07978f9d 
    4       00003cdc5ed35a0 693452b7ae2fd0c
```

Can someone please help me with the error. Can there be some other way to find all the possible cycles from this graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Directed_G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(data, 'from', 'to')
```

it creates a graph from the pandas dataframe and assigns that result to the name `Directed_G`.  It doesn't go and check first what sort of graph `Directed_G` was previously.  So it creates a graph using the default type (which is `Graph`) and the previous graph that was stored in `Directed_G` is overwritten, lost to the great garbage collector in the sky.  Then the command to find the cycles dies because it can't handle an undirected graph.

Add the optional argument `create_using=DiGraph` to your call to `from_pandas_dataframe`.

You should be aware that in the latest version of networkx `from_pandas_dataframe` has been removed: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.0/release/release_2.0.html

> Previously, the function `from_pandas_dataframe` assumed that the dataframe has edge-list like structures, but `to_pandas_dataframe` generates an adjacency matrix. We now provide four functions `from_pandas_edgelist`, `to_pandas_edgelist`, `from_pandas_adjacency`, and `to_pandas_adjacency`.